# expandable navbar when you click on icons

Tags: html, css, sidebar

Hey everyone so I want to do something rather simple. I want to make a side menu that has icons on it. When you click on those icons it should expand the navigation. Similar to how canva.com does their navigation when you get into a project. Start off with a small navbar with icons as shown in the first image and finally go to the full expanded as in the second image.

[image]

[image]

I have the following code that I used as a starting point and it kind of works but it expands on hover if anyone knows a good way to make a sidebar like this or how to get my sidebar to expand on click please let me know thanks.

```
  <div data-component="navbar">

<nav class="navbar p-0 fixed-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left rounded-0 border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#megamenu-dropdown" aria-controls="megamenu-dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i><span class="ml-3">Advanced</span>
      </button>
  
  <div><a class="navbar-brand px-1" href="#"><img src="http://kris.agentfire2.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/agentfire-shared-library/img/agentfire.svg" class="d-inline-block mt-1" alt="AgentFire Logo" height="40"></a>

  <div class="right-links float-right mr-4">
    <a href="#" class="home"><i class="fa fa-home mr-3"></i></a>
    
    <div class="d-inline dropdown rounded-0 mx-3">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="tools" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right rounded-0 text-center" aria-labelledby="tools">
        <a class="dropdown-item px-2" href="#">Recompile CSS</a>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /.dropdown -->
```

see full code at
https://codepen.io/Kamilica/pen/XRbvaL

Comment: you can control hover through CSS but for click, you need to control it JS

Comment: Okay any chance you could help me design that? I'm a backend developer trying to do front end code

Comment: This site is recognized to solve problems or challenges, not to solve a whole task, so please understand it clearly and sorry no one will help it in your task because that's not a problem that's a whole new task

Comment: @NishargShah not necessarily. You can do a clickable expandable menu with the use of `input type checkbox` and use the `:checked` selector

Comment: yes you can also do it like that, its css hack ;)